# Newbee trying hand on regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new to the regular expression and trying to build a expression wherein i want to check if the first three letters of the string are in upper case ?

I have expression like this "ALB.latin" or CAT.Cyrillic etc . i just want to check if the first three letters before the dot/period are capital and letter after the dot/period are in title case.

I have tried to build expression like to in FME test filter  `^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]$`.

Comment: Remove `$` end of string anchor. Use `^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]`. What is the programming language/method you are using it in?

Comment: You probably want to match the literal `.` so you have to escape it `\.`

Comment: @MuratK.: It is escaped, the question formatting was wrong.

Comment: I checked FME docs, but could not find any mentioning if the regex is anchors by default. Try `^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]+$` if `^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]` does not work.

Comment: You can use https://regex101.com to build and test regexes.

Comment: thank you both it worked

Comment: I wonder why this has been so heavily downvoted. It's a good question. It shows research effort up to a point, it includes a proper description, example input and output, and an attempt. It just has a bad title, but that can easily be fixed. It might be a smiple question, but we all start small.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `$` anchor from the pattern as it requires the end of string to appear right after the last `[A-Za-z]` subpattern matches an uppercase letter.

If you just need to check if the string starts with 3 uppercase ASCII letters, `.` and an ASCII letter, use

```
^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]
```

Or, if you also need to make sure there are 1 or more ASCII letters only at the end, add `+` between `[A-Za-z]` and `$`, to match 1 or more symbols defined in the `[a-zA-Z]` character class:

```
^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXZTn2/1).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you the solution.

```
^[A-Z]{3}\.[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

With this, Letter after DOT will be in Title case. But at least one title case letter should be there after DOT.